# TypeError: ShallowWrapper::state("isOpen") requires that `state` not be `null` or `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have been trying to run an unit test but i keep getting this error:

TypeError: ShallowWrapper::state("isOpen") requires that `state` not be `null` or `undefined`

I have seen something similar and was able to fix it - but I dont see where this is wrong at the moment

Using React JS - JEST AND ENZYME

```
here is the main file js


         closeModal = () => {
    //If close qfmodal, set modalvalues back to values
    let quickfilterModalValues = 
  Object.assign({},this.state.quickfilterValues);
    this.setState({
      selectedRecon_UID: null,
      refreshModalOpen: false, 
      descriptionModalOpen: false, 
      quickFilterModalOpen: false,

       <Modal isOpen={this.state.quickFilterModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>
      <div>
        <div className='fullmodal'>
          <div className='sidemodal_addnew_x' onClick={this.closeModal}>
            <FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' />
          </div>
        </div>    


   Here is the file.test.js
```

I did not include describe and beforeEach() test here -

```
  // defining this.props
  const baseProps = { 
  onClick,
  isOpen:false,
  }

 it("renders a modal portal", () => {
  const isOpen = wrapper.state("isOpen");
  const modalPortal = wrapper.find("div.fullmodal");
  expect(isOpen).toBeTruthy;
  expect(modalPortal).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I expect my snapshot to render MODAL as well

Comment: The main file doesn't look very complete, but do you have `state` defined on the Class? You can define it as an instance object or in the constructor.

Comment: I was not able to find the exact file but I included something similar on https://codesandbox.io/embed/k2qypovm95 under Worklows

Comment: The files under Workflows are empty. Checkout the `Class.jsx` file in this sandbox to see an example of how to initialize state in the constructor: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9lllw69wr

Comment: I just updated -  it didnt go through before

Comment: Constructor - i have defined already but it didnt solve the problem -

Comment: @MattyJ were you able to identify the problem ?

Comment: I added an answer. Your codesandbox is hard to test in because there are a lot of undefined dependencies. My guess is that you aren't defining `state` in the class correctly somehow :/ I was able to recreate the error, but defining `state` fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the `state` in the component not being defined.

If you have your `state` defined in the class constructor (or as an instance property), this error will not occur.

Example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {/* initial state */}
  }
}
```

You can debug whether you have state defined using enzyme's `instance` function in your test:

```
console.log(wrapper.instance().state);
```

If that prints out `null` or `undefined`, you are not defining the state object onto the instance correctly.

If that returns a valid object, then you should not see the `ShallowWrapper::state("isOpen")` error.

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1565 I tried to apply this as well - but it did not help

Comment: This didn't fix the issue.. still facing the same issue even  though state is already defined in the constructor

Comment: I am also still seeing this issue - where I have the state initialized in the constructor. Even if I directly setState() in the test, then print the instance, state === null.